# How to fix Jsoup query returning null

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to retrieve a value of an element with the id `loggedin` from a WebView using Jsoup, i'm pretty sure it exists in the webpage i'm loading but i keep getting null

this is the code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(webView.getUrl());
System.out.println("Webview url= "+webView.getUrl());
Elements loggedin = doc.select("#loggedin");
System.out.println("loggedin= "+ loggedin.first());
```

`System.out` output:

```
04-03 18:48:15.511 17236-17236/com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie I/System.out: Webview url= http://gestioncapteursincendie.herokuapp.com/
04-03 18:48:15.521 17236-17236/com.gci.gestioncapteursincendie I/System.out: loggedin= null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you use `Jsoup.parse` instead of `Jsoup.connect`

`parse` used for parsing html page, and `connect` to load page from specific url

Just replace `#loggedin` with `input#loggedin`

Example
`doc.select("input#loggedin");`

Or you can use `getElementById` to get `Element`

```
doc.getElementById("loggedin");
```